# How can I limit the number of characters transferred using Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am using ADF to transfer data from a source system to a destination. One of the columns is a Note column. Sometimes users write their life story in the Note column. When the text length exceeds 1,000 characters we get an error.

[image]

I only want to transfer the first 1,000 characters of the Note column. With TSQL I can write something such as `LEFT([Note],1000)`, but I am not sure how to do this from ADF.

How can I limit the number of characters transferred using Azure Data Factory?

Comment: hi, what's the source file format?

Comment: The source data is in the JSON format.

Comment: Hi @Tarzan, is the issue solved now? If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your source file is json format and note nested json, you can use Data flow to achieve it.

In Data flow, use a [Derived Column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-derived-column) to limit the number of characters.

Your Derived Column expression should like this:

```
substring(note,1,1000)
```

For example, I only want the first 20 characters:

[image]

[image]

HTH.

Comment: This looks like a Data Flow. The data source is GraphQL which sends data in the JSON format. The destination is SQL Server. Is there a way to call a GraphQL endpoint using a Data Flow?

Comment: @Tarzan Yes, it's a work flow. In Data Factory only the Data Flow can help us modify the data/schema. Copy active doesn't support it and can't do that. Some sources are not supported both in Copy active and Data Flow. I don't how you set the source in Copy active,  if you could't set it in Data Flow, it usually means not supported.